# Can't connect to docker app locally using docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm on Linux and trying to run a Rails application in Docker with docker-compose.
I probably made a mistake somewhere because the application appear to be starting fine with no errors, but I can't connect locally to the port I setup.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.6.2-alpine

RUN apk --update add --virtual build_deps \
      build-base ruby-dev libc-dev linux-headers tzdata \
      openssl-dev postgresql-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S appgroup && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S appuser -G appgroup

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN gem install bundler
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install --jobs 4

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app

RUN chown -R appuser:appgroup .

EXPOSE 3000/tcp

RUN cd /usr/src/app
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    expose:
      - 5432
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres@db/thedb
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=yada
      - SERVE_API_DOCS=true
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

If I connect to `0.0.0.0:3000` or `localhost:3000` the service doesn't answer (and I see nothing in console where docker-compose started - confident that localhost:3000 doesn't get to container:3000).
Also `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' CONTAINER` returns an empty line.

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8007021836ec        thing_web   "bundle exec rails s…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        3000/tcp            thing_web_run_87ddb5063651
9addc47d5197        postgres                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago         Up About an hour    5432/tcp            thing_db_1
```

Does anybody have any clue? Tips on debugging are welcome too.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `expose` with `ports` in your `docker-compose.yml`? `expose` doesn't expose ports to host machine, `ports` does. Please refer to the document here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose

Comment: Sorry I’m an idiot, I had ports, just changed it out of desperation and forgot to correct

Comment: What happens if you don't specify port and host in the command section? It should default to those values, but maybe `0.0.0.0` is resolving weirdly.

Comment: Also a good trick for debugging here is to run `docker-compose run web /bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`. This drops you into a shell session inside docker, upon which time you should be able to debug what's wrong in a few minutes in all likelihood